# Is there a way to serialize an arbitrary javascript object in such a way that it can be restored to be exactly as it was at a later time?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

Among many objects, I need to serialize an instance of a paper.js [`Point`](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/). JSON serialization isn't enough, because it omits all functions, getters/setters, and fails completely on objects with circular references, all of which I need. I can't write custom serialization for every object that I want to serialize, because there are too many, and they all contain too many properties. Is there a way that I can serialize this object, and deserialize it later such that the deserialized copy behaves the same way?

Comment: The code doesn't change.  Only the state does, and JSON is perfectly adequate for the state.

Comment: For `Point`, surely you only need `x`, `y` and _"to know it's a Point"_ (which may be the harder bit) so you can run it back through the _constructor_?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid, because there are many different objects that I need to serialize. "Knowing" it's a point requires me to write some sort of custom serialization. I need a generic way of doing this.

Comment: This looks promising: http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/07/json-serialize-and-deserialize.html